# ActiveRecord where method datetime passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

Thanks for your continuing support in my latest venture in a Rails app. It's been a while since I've made something in Rails so here is my latest question. I appreciate the help you've all given in the past.

I have a Model called Event.rb which contains a date:date and time:time fields for the Event.

I also have a method inside of the model which is..

```
def begins
    DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.min, time.sec)
end
```

As I can't see if something has truly passed because I only have Date and Time separate so I need them together.

My question is...

I want to be able to add in the DateTime :begins into the following other method in my Model...

```
def self.past
    where("date <= ?", TIME_NOW)
end
```

Just like I have a method which is...

```
def upcoming?
    self.date >= Time.now
end
```

Which I could easily change self.date to begins and would past I would imagine?

Thanks!

Comment: With `self.past` are you intending just check if the individual instance has past or did you want to query the database for past events?

Comment: For that one it would just be for use in doing `@events = Event.past` and then the other one for `Event.find(1).upcoming?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work for querying the database for past events using your existing `date` and `time` columns:

```
scope :past, lambda {
  where("date <= ? and time <= ?",
         Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m"),
         Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
       )
}

past_events = Event.past
```

For checking the current instance, you could continue to use your `begins` method:

```
def past?
  begins < DateTime.now
end

@event = Event.first
@event.past?
```

Comment: Thanks, I do get the following error with this however.. `PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2013-30-11"
LINE 1: ...s"  WHERE "events"."flagged" IS NULL AND (date >= '2013-30-1...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.` Unsure how to solve the HINT.

Comment: You might try sending a date `where("date <= date(?)...` or you could use postgres' `now()` function: `where("date <= now() and time <= localtime())`. I'm not certain if now() is the best idea though because you may have to worry about your users' timezones.